# How to know if List is empty or not in Struts2?

Tags: list, struts2

I have one List. Which is fetch from java class to jsp page. I want to display this List in jsp page but, if List is empty then display one error message otherwise display List's item.

```
<s:iterator value="productList">
    <tr style="background-color: #99CCFF">      
        <td><s:property value="pid"/></td>
        <td><s:property value="productname"/></td>
        <td><s:property value="producttype"/></td>
        <td><s:property value="productprice"/></td>
        <td><s:property value="shopname"/></td>
        <td><s:property value="productcity"/></td>
        <td><s:property alue="ownername"/></td>                 
    </tr>
</s:iterator>
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use Struts2 `<s:if>` and `<s:else>` tags for conditional checking like this:

```
<s:if test="%{getProductList().isEmpty()}">
   Error
</s:if>
<s:else>
     <s:iterator value="productList">
        <tr style="background-color: #99CCFF">      
            <td><s:property value="pid"/></td>
            <td><s:property value="productname"/></td>
            <td><s:property value="producttype"/></td>
            <td><s:property value="productprice"/></td>
            <td><s:property value="shopname"/></td>
            <td><s:property value="productcity"/></td>
            <td><s:property alue="ownername"/></td>                 
        </tr>
    </s:iterator> 
</s:else>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<s:if test="%{productList.isEmpty()}">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="7">Empty</td>
    </tr>
</s:if>
<s:else>
    <s:iterator value="productList">
        <tr style="background-color: #99CCFF">      
            <td><s:property value="pid"/></td>
            <td><s:property value="productname"/></td>
            <td><s:property value="producttype"/></td>
            <td><s:property value="productprice"/></td>
            <td><s:property value="shopname"/></td>
            <td><s:property value="productcity"/></td>
            <td><s:property alue="ownername"/></td>                 
        </tr>
    </s:iterator>
</s:else>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apaet from using `productList.isEmpty()` you can also check the size of `productList`
Like

```
<s:if test="%{productList.size>0}">
 <table>
         <s:iterator value="productList">
            <tr style="background-color: #99CCFF">      
              <td><s:property value="pid"/></td>
              <td><s:property value="productname"/></td>
              <td><s:property value="producttype"/></td>
              <td><s:property value="productprice"/></td>
              <td><s:property value="shopname"/></td>
              <td><s:property value="productcity"/></td>
              <td><s:property alue="ownername"/></td>                 
          </tr>
      </s:iterator>
 </table>
 </s:if>
<s:else>
   <div> No data found</div>
</s:else>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also this shorter syntax

```
<s:if test="productList.empty">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="7">Empty</td>
    </tr>
</s:if>
<s:else>
    <s:iterator value="productList">
        <tr style="background-color: #99CCFF">      
            <td><s:property value="pid"/></td>
            <td><s:property value="productname"/></td>
            <td><s:property value="producttype"/></td>
            <td><s:property value="productprice"/></td>
            <td><s:property value="shopname"/></td>
            <td><s:property value="productcity"/></td>
            <td><s:property alue="ownername"/></td>                 
        </tr>
    </s:iterator>
</s:else>
```